# db converts decimal number wrong

Tags: php, database, forms

Custom form is taking decimal but db inserts whole numbers but with a .0 behind. Why won't it give me the correct decimal number ?

Db field

```
    fiske_vaegt DECIMAL( 2,1 ) NOT NULL,
```

Form input field

```
    <p><input type="number" step="any" name="fiske_vaegt" id="fiske_vaegt" />kg</p>
```

CHECK the fiske_vaegt field if i Input 2.4 it changes it to 2.0 and 2.7 to 3.0
[image]

Anyone who have any experience with this goddamned problem?

post

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
$fiske_vaegt = $_POST['fiske_vaegt'];
```

}

insert

```
$registrering = $wpdb->insert( 
$wpdb->prefix . 'registreringer',
    array(
        'fiske_vaegt'       => $fiske_vaegt
        ),
    array(
        '%d'
        )
    );
```

Comment: The obvious reason should be the code that handles the fiske_vaegt value and sends it to the query/db. I suppose you use Mysql and by default, it should honor the decimal place and not round them.

Comment: I've added the post method into the question. I dont really see the problem i'm getting

Comment: %d is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within `$wpdb->insert`, you are using `%d` which is used to store integer, use `%f` instead which will store float/decimal values.

```
$registrering = $wpdb->insert( 
    $wpdb->prefix . 'registreringer',
    array(
        'fiske_vaegt'       => $fiske_vaegt
    ),
    array(
        '%f'
    )
);
```

Comment: Gave you the answer points for best illustration of the answer

Answer (score 2):

'%d' modifier is for integers, not decimals use the %f (floats or the %s strings) and it would save it correctly.